# SQL string function, permutation of words

Tags: sql, postgresql

The table has a column `name`. The column contains first and last names. How to make a select query so that the last name is displayed first, and then the first letter of the first name?

Comment: 1) tag your database 2) provide sample data 3) show us your desired output

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the database that you are using.  This is for mySQL:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(TRIM( SUBSTR(name, LOCATE(' ', name)) ),
        ' ',  LEFT(name, 1) )as ShortName

FROM [your_table_name_here]
```

Given the inputs of:

```
Jack Smith
Mark Anthony
```

The query will return:

```
Smith J
Anthony M
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mySQL the following example will work.
See the DBfiddle link at the bottom to test and modify.
In other SQL engines you will find the same functions, but depending on which one they may have different names and syntaxes.

> ```
> select
> name,
> concat(
>   substring(
>            name,
>            locate(' ',name) + 1,
>            25) ,
>   ' ',
>   substring(name,1,1)
> ) formatted_name
> from names
> ```
>
> ```
> name           | formatted_name
> :------------- | :-------------
> Vladimir Putin | Putin V       
> Boris Johnson  | Johnson B
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=636a2ed70d2458c09a8fee97d6129703)*